Analytic continuation and invariance under complex Lorentz transformation
I already asked (here) but the half remains.
A holomorphic function (called Wightman distribution) $w_N$ has following property.

Domain is an open set in $(\mathbb{C}^D)^{N-1}$ .
Invariant under real proper Lorentz transformation. That is $w_N(\zeta_1,...,\zeta_{N-1})=w_N(\Lambda\zeta_1,...,\Lambda\zeta_{N-1})$ for all $\Lambda$ in real proper Lorentz group for $\mathbb{R}^D$.
For an neighborhood $U$ of $id_{\mathbb{C}^D} \in L(\mathbb{C})$(complex proper Lorentz group) , $U \to \mathbb{C}, \Lambda\mapsto w_N(\Lambda\zeta_1,...,\Lambda\zeta_{N-1})$ is holomorphic.

My textbook says  $w_N(\zeta_1,...,\zeta_{N-1})=w_N(\Lambda\zeta_1,...,\Lambda\zeta_{N-1})$ holds for $\Lambda$ in complex proper Lorentz group for $\mathbb{C}^D$.
 But I have no idea to prove if from properties above.
Could you help? Any advice or good reference also helps me. Thanks for reading.

Edit
I came up a way.
A new holomorphic function $w'_N$ can be defined as $w'_N(\Lambda \zeta_1,...,\Lambda\zeta_{N-1})=w_N(\zeta_1,...,\zeta_{N-1})$ for $\Lambda \in U$ : open neighborhood of $id_{\mathbb{C}}$. $w'_N$ is probably analytic continuation of $w_N$ and the uniqueness of analytic continuation means $w'_N=w_N$ then $w_N \circ \Lambda=w_N$ for $\Lambda \in L(\mathbb{C}
)$.
Am I on right way?

Professional answered my question and I understand. https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/837167/353831
